# How to show size chart content of the current product vendor in shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

We generally shows the content of the 'Size Chart' page in popup on product detail page in shopify. But if the store have too many vendors/brands and all the vendors have its own different sizes then how can we filter size chart by its vendor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we can show the size chart in popup by following the simple steps given in the below link -

[Create Size Chart On Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/products/features/add-size-chart#creating-a-size-chart-snippet-non-sectioned-themes-specific)

Here I am showing the content of the current product vendor in popup window.

So firstly we have to create pages on the name of the vendor for example if the brand names are - Puma, Nike and Adidas, we need to create their pages by their name. 
Now create the navigation by giving any name for example - `size-chart-vendor-menu` and add all these vendors as a child and link to their pages.
See the below image -

[image]

Now on the product detail replace `{{ pages.size-chart.content }}` with the below code.

```
          {% assign proVendor = product.vendor | handleize %}
          {% for link in linklists.size-chart-vendor-menu.links %}
            {% assign pageTitle = link.title | handleize %}
              {% if proVendor == pageTitle %}   
              {% assign proSizeChart = proVendor %}
                  {{ pages[proSizeChart].content }}
              {% endif %}          
          {% endfor %}
```